# Append to a file in Go

Tags: file-io, go

So I can read from a local file like so:

```
data, error := ioutil.ReadFile(name)
```

And I can write to a local file

```
ioutil.WriteFile(filename, content, permission)
```

But how can I append to a file? Is there a built in method?

Comment: Yep, you got it. The ioutil functions are just conveniences that take care of common tasks. If you want more control, see the os package.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

This answers works in Go1:

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0600)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer f.Close()

if _, err = f.WriteString(text); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Why not 0666 file mode? I thought that was a better default value.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar: see [another comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245193/c-linux-file-permission-problem-with-open#comment-2203227) and _[man umask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html)_. With typical umask of 022, you'll get typical permissions: `0666 & ~022 = 0644 = rw-r--r--`

Comment: os.O_CREATE is nice to include if the file might not already exist.

Comment: maybe a bit stupid question but why would it need both `os.O_APPEND` and `os.O_WRONLY`? This works for sure but why both?

Comment: os.O_APPEND and os.O_WRONLY
os.O_APPEND is to control behaviour in this case to Append mode so it does not need to maintain a file pointer.
os.O_WRONLY is to state the file mode, wether read,write, or both, in this case write.

Comment: I realize the docs say `Exactly one of O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR must be specified.`, but couldn't `O_WRONLY` be _implied_ by `O_APPEND`? I can't think of a case where you would ever open with mode `O_RDONLY|O_APPEND` (and only a contrived use case for `O_RDWR|O_APPEND`). Ya know, `os.Append` seems like a reasonable addition to the stdlib, alongside the other wrappers `os.Open` and `os.Create`

Answer (score 74):

Go docs has a [perfect example](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#example_OpenFile_append) :

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // If the file doesn't exist, create it, or append to the file
    f, err := os.OpenFile("access.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if _, err := f.Write([]byte("appended some data\n")); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

Figured it out

[More info](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/de9a10ba4c8ed906)

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644) 

n, err := f.WriteString(text) 

f.Close()
```

Comment: you should also use os.O_WRONLY

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851692/golang-bad-file-descriptor#answer-33852107                
"by default you get a read-only file descriptor."

Answer (score 8):

... I would use fmt.Fprintf, because accept a writer... and a connection or files will be a writer and easy to write in a way of string...

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer f.Close()
fmt.Fprintf(f, "%s", text)
```

I hope this help!

Javier,

Answer (score 6):

If you also want to create the file

`f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)`

Answer (score 6):

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer f.Close()

if _, err = f.WriteString(text); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Made a slight change from the one provided in the golang site by adding flags to the `os.OpenFile` function which by default will only allow reading of a file and not editing amongst other features.

Comment: What is the change and why?

Comment: @Mitar what exactly do u mean cause I'm using different functions. Though, if u are asking about how the appending is done specifically I'll point u to the `os.OpenFile` function which can accepts flags for what u can do with a file, i.e. u can create the said file if it doesn't exist using this flag `os.O_CREATE` or for this case u can append using the `os.O_APPEND` flag for allowing to append to the file.                                      ps. u can use a couple of them at the same time

Comment: You said that you made a slight change to the highest voted comment. But I do not see any change from the accepted answer. What is the change?

Comment: Only chmod is different and set to 644?

Comment: @Mitar sorry didn't get what u meant before, but yes, by default u are only allowed to read, so u need to specify the rights to said file.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear as well. I am saying that you should update your answer and explain in it what you changed.

Comment: @mitar done editing :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to add the contents of file`current` to the file `all`, then below code is working:

```golang
func updateTrx() {
    var err error
    var f *os.File

    // If the file doesn't exist, create it, or append to the file
    if f, err = os.OpenFile("all.csv", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error", err)
        }
    }()

    var current *os.File
    if current, err = os.OpenFile("current.csv", os.O_RDONLY, 0); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error", err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err := current.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error", err)
        }
    }()

    if fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(current); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error", err)
    } else {
        if _, err := f.Write([]byte(fileBytes)); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```