# Setting permissions based on the program trying to access a kernel module

Tags: permissions, linux-kernel, kernel

I have written a kernel module that creates a /proc file and reads values written into it from a user program,say user.c

Now I want restrict permissions for this /proc file.I have restricted permissions based on userid using the 'current' kernel variable by checking current->euid.

My question: Is there a way to restrict this based on the program too? i.e. only user.c should be able to write to this proc file and not any other program.I could not find any parameters in task_struct that would help me do this. Can you please suggest a way  to do this?

Comment: When you open a file, please use permission parameters also. Please see the link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245193/c-linux-file-permission-problem-with-open

Answer (score 1):

In your proc writer implementation (that is, inside the kernel module) the best you can do is check the value of current (a struct task *), which holds (among other things) valuable fields such as comm (16-character argv[0]), pid, uid, etc (Basically, everything you see in /proc//status. You can also check the original exe name (like you see in /proc//exe), to see if it's a well known path. You can then return an error.

Caveat: Anyone could rename their opening process to be one of your "allowed" programs, if you go by "comm", and there are ways to defeat the "exe" protection. This will only make it slightly harder, but not impossible for someone to get around. A more comprehensive and stronger solution would require you to peek at the user mode memory of the program, which is possible, but too complicated for a brief answer.

Note: Permission parameters won't work, don't even bother. They go by classic UNIX ACL, which is u/g/o - so you can't filter by PID.