# What are `open()` default permissions at file creation?

Tags: c, file-permissions

I made a little project some weeks ago, but it somehow didn't work anymore recently (or at least, not like it previously worked).

It had to create a file with `open()`, and fill it with some content.

```
[...]
int fd=open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
/* write content */
close(fd);
[...]
```

The problem was just that it recently didn't create the file with the right permissions anymore (it was created with `0110` when the problem was occurring)

I now know that I just have to specify the permissions like this :

```
int fd=open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0700); /* (for instance) */
```

But the project still worked on some computers (Didn't work on OSX, but did work on a Linux, on which it was created with `0640`, so it still worked because I still had reading permission).

So here is my question:

- How are those default permissions defined for `open()` function at file creation?

(If I don't explicitly pass it to my `open()` call as a parameter.)

Comment: What does your manual page tell you?

Comment: "[The `mode`] argument *must* be supplied when `O_CREAT` is specified in flags". (Emphasis mine) This makes it sound like it's undefined behaviour when you don't, and I do indeed get junk when I omit it (`--wS--S--T`).

Comment: @ikegami And that undefined behavior could result in something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2245193/6850771).

Comment: One of the wonders of undefined behaviour is that sometimes it will seem to work — and at other times, it won't.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Indeed. My bad, I messed my copy-paste, I edited my post. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default. You must specify them when you use `O_CREAT`.

---

According to the documentation on my system,

> [The `mode`] argument *must* be supplied when `O_CREAT` is specified in flags

(Emphasis mine)

This makes it sound like it's undefined behaviour when you don't, and I do indeed get junk when I omit it (`--wS--S--T`).

Comment: `[open()] require an additional argument mode_t mode; the file is created with mode mode as described in chmod(2) and modified by the process' umask value (see umask(2)).`

It looks like you're right! My bad, I was searching for a "permissions" keyword in my man.

Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the mode arguments as an integer containing a set of bit flags.  Something like:

```
 int fd=open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
```

See the man page for chmod.  The call also uses the process umask to limit things.